# Tictoc Tutorial:Why are the positions of the module vectors overlapping,not separate?

Tags: omnet++

I am learing the OMNeT++ With Tictoc Tutorial,however I encounter a problem in the part4.1 "More than two nodes".

According to the tutorial, the tictoc10.ned can generate six simple modules in different locations.But there is just a module vector icon in my ned file even if I completely copy the tictoc10.ned file.

I guess there maybe some properties which I need to set but it doesn't work at all.And I also scrolling through the 'simulation manual' with no result.

simple Txc10
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=block/routing");
    gates:
        input in[];
        output out[];
}
network Tictoc10
{
    submodules:
        tic[6]: Txc10;    //this line should generate 6 Txc10 modules with 
                          //different positions
    //ingnore the connections
}

Thank you for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two places to pay attention to.

1.as like the former answer says,the NED editor in the IDE displays only the structures present in the NED file. And you can find the several module icons when you run the simulation.
2.The size of the network in the 'Design' mode of the NED file need to be adjusted according to the quatity of the submodules in this network. In this example,the size of network is so small that submodules overlapp and the connections between can't be found.After I enlarge it the problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

The NED editor in the IDE displays only the structures present in the NED file. I.e. you will not see several icons in the graphical editor only a single icon that represents the vector. On the other hand, when you actually run the simulation, the correct number of instances from the node will be instantiated and the autolayouter will arrange them.

Comment: Thank you!
It's strange that I didn't seem to see several nodes when I ran the simulation before.Anyway I found it this time and appreciate your answer.

But their positions are so confusing that it can't show the connections of the gates.And the effect of button "Re-layout" dose not seem to be very good.

So the "autolayout" which you say is same to "Re-layout" button?And do you have some good ideas to improver their layout to show the connections better?

Comment: Obviously, if you don't have connections between the submodules, the autolayouter cannot work out a good layout. You can force various layouts manually. See the P display tag. https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:graphics:submodule-positioning

ring layout would be a good start.

Comment: If that answers your question, you should accept it on the UI so it will be categorized as correct so other people will find it more easily.